# How to read PDF bookmarks programmatically

Tags: c#, pdf, command-line, bookmarks

I'm using a PDF converter to access the graphical data within a PDF. Everything works fine, except that I don't get a list of the bookmarks. Is there a command-line app or a C# component that can read a PDF's bookmarks? I found the iText and SharpPDF libraries and I'm currently looking through them. Have you ever done such a thing?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try the following code

```
PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(filename);

IList<Dictionary<string, object>> bookmarks = SimpleBookmark.GetBookmark(pdfReader);

for(int i=0;i<bookmarks.Count;i++)
{
    MessageBox.Show(bookmarks[i].Values.ToArray().GetValue(0).ToString());

    if (bookmarks[i].Count > 3)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(bookmarks[i].ToList().Count.ToString());
    }
}
```

Note: Don't forget to add iTextSharp DLL to your project.

Comment: `SimpleBookmark.GetBookmark` will only return the top-level bookmarks. The nested bookmarks will be listed in the parent's dictionary, which you can test for by using `if (bookmarks[i].ContainsKey("Kids")) { /* show child bookmarks */ }`. `bookmarks[i]["Kids"]` will be an `IList<Dictionary<string, object>>` as well.

Answer (score 5):

As the bookmarks are in a tree structure (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)), 
I've used some recursion here to collect all bookmarks and it's children.

iTextSharp solved it for me.

```
dotnet add package iTextSharp
```

Collected all bookmarks with the following code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;

namespace PdfManipulation
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StringBuilder bookmarks = ExtractAllBookmarks("myPdfFile.pdf");
        }

        private static StringBuilder ExtractAllBookmarks(string pdf)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdf);
            IList<Dictionary<string, object>> bookmarksTree = SimpleBookmark.GetBookmark(reader);
            foreach (var node in bookmarksTree)
            {
                sb.AppendLine(PercorreBookmarks(node).ToString());
            }
            return RemoveAllBlankLines(sb);
        }

        private static StringBuilder RemoveAllBlankLines(StringBuilder sb)
        {
            return new StringBuilder().Append(Regex.Replace(sb.ToString(), @"^\s+$[\r\n]*", string.Empty, RegexOptions.Multiline));
        }

        private static StringBuilder PercorreBookmarks(Dictionary<string, object> bookmark)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.AppendLine(bookmark["Title"].ToString());
            if (bookmark != null && bookmark.ContainsKey("Kids"))
            {
                IList<Dictionary<string, object>> children = (IList<Dictionary<string, object>>) bookmark["Kids"];
                foreach (var bm in children)
                {
                    sb.AppendLine(PercorreBookmarks(bm).ToString());
                }
            }
            return sb;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You might try [Docotic.Pdf library](https://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/) for the task if you are fine with a commercial solution.

Here is a sample code to list all top-level items from bookmarks with some of their properties.

```
using (PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument("file.pdf"))
{
    PdfOutlineItem root = doc.OutlineRoot;
    foreach (PdfOutlineItem item in root.Children)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1} child nodes, points to page {2})",
            item.Title, item.ChildCount, item.PageIndex);
    }
}
```

[PdfOutlineItem](https://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/api/pdfoutlineitem) class also provides properties related to outline item styles and more.

Disclaimer: I work for the vendor of the library.

Answer (score 2):

[You can use the PDFsharp library.](http://www.pdfsharp.net/MainPage.ashx) It is published under the MIT License so it can be used even in corporate development. Here is an untested example.

```
using PdfSharp.Pdf;

using (PdfDocument document = PdfReader.IO.Open("bookmarked.pdf", IO.PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import))
{
    PdfDictionary outline = document.Internals.Catalog.Elements.GetDictionary("/Outlines");
    PrintBookmark(outline);
}

void PrintBookmark(PdfDictionary bookmark)
{
    Console.WriteLine(bookmark.Elements.GetString("/Title"));
    for (PdfDictionary child = bookmark.Elements.GetDictionary("/First"); child != null; child = child.Elements.GetDictionary("/Next"))
    {
        PrintBookmark(child);
    }
}
```

### Gotchas:

- PdfSharp doesn't support open pdf's over version 1.6 very well. (throws: `cannot handle iref streams. the current implementation of pdfsharp cannot handle this pdf feature introduced with acrobat 6`)
- There are many types of strings in PDFs which PDFsharp returns as is including UTF-16BE strings. [(7.9.2.1 ISO32000 2008)](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf)

Comment: any chance you can help on this question please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39531162/create-multiple-pdf-files-from-one-input-pdf-file-split-using-bookmarks

Answer (score 1):

If a commercial library is an option for you you could give [Amyuni PDF Creator .Net](http://www.amyuni.com/en/developer/pdfcreator/features.html) a try.

Use the class [Amyuni.PDFCreator.IacDocument.RootBookmark](http://www.amyuni.com/WebHelp/Amyuni_PDF_Creator_for_NET/Working_with_Bookmarks_NET/Properties/IacDocument.RootBookmark_Property.htm) to retrieve the root of the bookmarks' tree, then the properties in [IacBookmark](http://www.amyuni.com/WebHelp/Amyuni_PDF_Creator_for_NET/Working_with_Bookmarks_NET/Properties/IacBookmark.Title_Property.htm) to access each tree element, to navigate through the tree, and to add, edit or remove elements if needed.

*Usual disclaimer applies*